Can this boy pull himself up to the roof?

The boy stood on the box, which had a pulley and a rope fixed to the roof. The rope wrapped around the pulley and was held by the boy's hand. Can this boy raise himself to the roof by pulling a rope?
I think it seems impossible because there is torque that cannot be balanced.

which torque???

This question is similar to: Pulling myself up with a pulley attached to myself. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hint: The force with which the boy needs to pull is twice the weight of himself plus  the box $ F = g( M_\text{Boy}+ M_\text{Box})$.

not the twice, just once

Voting to reopen, since the answers to the linked question are not that good

@basics it is an exact duplicate, so the proper thing to do is take your answer form here and post it there, not re-open this one.

Good thinking to consider torque. The question linked as duplicate does not consider that.

not the same. Depends on the details of the question. Here there's an extra block. Is the OP considering finite dimension of the pulley, and relative position of the guy on the block? and so on

As shown in the linked answers, the situation depicted is the same as if the boy were "rope climbing". The only difference is that instead of pulling himself up on the rope by pulling down on it, in the picture the boy is pulling up on the rope in order to have him and the platform move up.

Note also that the pulley offers no mechanical advantage. It only serves to redirect the boys applied force.

Neglecting the dimension of the pulley, or assuming everything is centered and the guy is pulling in the vertical direction, the guy can pull up himself along with the block, if he provides a force that equilibrates the sum of his weight and the weight of the block,
$$F = W_{man} + W_{block} \ .$$
This can be proved with a basic use of equilibrium equations and actino/reaction principle.


But this pulley has a diameter, so it seems that the balance of torque needs to be considered.
